# What is Azure Eventhub Python SDK v5.x.x equivalent of EPHOptions.keep_alive_interval which was a part of v1.x.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-eventhub

I have been migrating Python Eventhub SDK from v1 to v5.
As **EPHOptions** is deprecated in new version. I wont be able to use it in v5.x.x

I want to use EPHOptions.keep_alive_interval, What is its equivalent in Python Eventhub SDK v5.x.x ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent class in V5.x.x SDK by now.

> In V1, EventProcessorHost allowed you to balance the load between
> multiple instances of your program when receiving events.
>
> In V5, EventHubConsumerClient allows you to do the same with the
> receive() method if you pass a CheckpointStore to the constructor.

In V5, you need to use EventHubConsumerClient  to receive events. But there is no parameter to set `keep_alive_interval`.

Reference:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/migration_guide.md#migrating-code-from-eventprocessorhost-to-eventhubconsumerclient-for-receiving-events

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/azure/eventhub/_consumer_client.py